# Counting elements of a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table of 200 elements, elements are '0', '1', '2'. I have participate them into groups for 20 elements each one. Then I have calculate how many '0', '1', '2' are in each part. And then in vectors n1, n2, n0 write the answers.
For example: n1=(3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,6,1); so there are 3 elements of '1' in first part and so on.
How can I do that?

Comment: see `Partition` and `Tally`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  You say a "table of 200 elements" -- is this a list (vector) or two dimensional table?

Comment: All your questions are about the same thing and are closely related. And your two first questions answer this one IMO.

Comment: antalstrempel, in the future if a question of yours is "put on hold" please do not post a new of nearly identical content; instead edit your question to improve it, to try to address reason for the **[on hold]**.  In this case you didn't even answer my simple question above; please do so.

Comment: I have now marked this as a duplicate because by the only way that I can interpret this it is, apart from `Partition` which you were shown in answer to your prior question.  If this is not what you want you can still edit *this question* to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do what you want!
Here an example of the kind of groups of 20 you mentioned. I assume  '0', '1', '2' in your elements list are strings.

```
list = RandomChoice[{"0", "1", "2"}, {10, 20}];
```

Now the counting is easy. and you get those n0,n1,n2.

```
Transpose@(Sort[Tally[#]] & /@ ToExpression[list])[[All, All, 2]]
```

> {{2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 9, 4, 10, 7, 8}, {11, 5, 3, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5}, {7,
>      6, 9, 6, 8, 7, 10, 8, 10, 7}}

As mentioned in the comment here goes the `BinCount` version.

```
Transpose[BinCounts[#, {0, 10, 1}] & /@ ToExpression[list]][[1 ;; 3]]
```

Comment: `BinCounts` might be better (this will break if any count happens to be zero)